# How to replace a case insensitive string in objective-c iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, case-sensitive

I have a long string of some characters.  I want to replace some chars with other chars.

For example

```
string1="Hello WORLD12";
string2="world";

string1= search string2 in string1 and replace it; 
//need this method in objective c

string1="Hello world12";
```

Comment: It's not a clear question, explain your problem.

Comment: It looks like he wants to replace only the part of string1 that is in caps. Not the entire string.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use `NSRange` to grab the replacing string and then use`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` function to replace the characters in string.

```
NSString *string1 = "Hello WORLD12";
NSString *string2 = "world";
NSRange *range = [string1 rangeOfString:string2];
if (range.length > 0){
    NSString *newString = [string1 substringFromIndex:range.location+6];
    [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:newString withString:string2];
}
```

Answer (score 55):

If by case insensitive you mean the lower case replacement, Ken Pespisa has your answer, but if case insensitivity is about your search string you can do this:

```
[mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"searchString" withString:@"replaceString" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mystring length])];
```

for more info see documentation of:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options range:(NSRange)searchRange;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myString = @"select name SELECT college Select row";
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"select" withString:@"update" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
output: @"update name update college update row";
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer by providing more information, explanating the rationale of the solution and adding formating

Answer (score 1):

You can call the NSString method [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString)

```
NSString *string1 = "Hello WORLD12";
NSString *string2 = "world";

NSString *string3 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"WORLD" withString:string2];
```